# Querying data from AWS Amplify datastore

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I am new to using AWS and I am trying to use its datastore for an Android Application. However, I'm having difficulty working with the data itself. I am struggling to return records from tables to work with from within the application. I'll explain what I mean:

This is the code provided by AWS to query a table and log all records:

```
Amplify.DataStore.query(
                User.class,
                items -> {
                    while (items.hasNext()) {
                        User item = items.next();
                        System.out.println("Username: " + item.getUsername());
                        Log.i("Amplify", "Id " + item.getId());
                    }
                },
                failure -> Log.e("Amplify", "Could not query DataStore", failure)
        );
```

I have just put this code in a method
`getUsers()`

So I have a button to get all the users:

```
    Button btnQuery = findViewById(R.id.btnQuery);
        btnQuery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                System.out.println("Button click registered.");

                getUsers();

                System.out.println("getUsers() exit");
                //System.out.println("Starting to print users");
                System.out.println(users);
            }
        });
```

The problem is that `System.out.println("getUsers() exit");` is outputed to the console *before* the `getUsers()` method logs all of the table's records to the console. I have also tried to put `getUsers()` inside a thread and join that thread, and get the same output. The same with trying to use AsyncTask. This is making it confusing and difficult for me to work with the data as I can't add each record to an ArrayList and then return that `ArrayList` because the `ArrayList` is returned *before* any records are added to it.

Any help with this is much appreciated. Anything else you need me to add to this I will be happy to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a callback using interface and pass it to `getUsers();`:

**PrintCallback.java**

```
interface PrintCallback{
    void executeCallback(String str);
}
```

Modify signature to `getUsers()` method to:

```
getUsers(PrintCallback callback){...}
```

In the Button:

```
Button btnQuery = findViewById(R.id.btnQuery);
        btnQuery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                System.out.println("Button click registered.");

                getUsers(new PrintCallback() {
                   @Override
                   public void executeCallback(String str) {

                   System.out.println("getUsers() exit");
                   //System.out.println("Starting to print users");
                   System.out.println(users);

                   }
                });

                
            }
        });
```

Finally, in the query:

```
callback.executeCallback("someString");
```

Comment: Sorry, does that final callback.executeCallback() go within the query, above or below the while loop? So far what I've tried, this callback does not solve my problem :/

Comment: I got it to work! Your solution worked like a charm (I just didn't implement it correctly the first time around). Thanks very much, you're a life saver :D

Comment: Of course! I would also up-vote your answer for you but I don't have enough reputation yet D: pls accept a hypothetical up-vote